# Implement a function that blends two colors encoded with RGB565 using Alpha blending

Tags: c++, image-processing, bit-manipulation, rgb, alphablending

I am trying to implement a function that blends two colors encoded with RGB565 using Alpha blending
Crgb565 = (1-a)Argb565 + a*Brgb565

Where a is the alpha parameter, and the alpha blending value of 0.0-1.0 is mapped to an unsigned char value on the range 0-32.
we can  choose to use a five bit representation for a instead, thus restricting it to the range of 0-31 (effectively mapping to an alpha blending value of 0.0-0.96875).

Following code I am trying to implement, can you please suggest better way wrt less temp variable , memory optimization (number of multiplications and required memory accesses ),Is my logic for  alpha bending is correct? I am not getting correct result/expected output, Seems like I am missing something, please review the code, Every suggest is appreciated, have some doubt based on alpha parameter. I have put my doubts in code comment section. Is there any way to shortening the alpha blending equations(division operation)?

=====================================================

```
unsigned short blend_rgb565(unsigned short A, unsigned short B, unsigned char Alpha) 
    { 
        unsigned short res = 0; 
        // Alpha converted from [0..255] to [0..31] (8 bit to 5 bit)        
/* I want the alpha parameter (0-32), do i need to add something in Alpha  before right shift?? */
        Alpha = Alpha >> 3;  
    
        // Split Image A into  R, G, B components
        /*Do I need to take it as unsigned short or uint8_t also work fine ??*/
        unsigned short A_r =  A >> 11;
        unsigned short A_g = (A >> 5) & ((1u << 6) - 1); // ((1u << 6) - 1) --> 00000000 00111111
        unsigned short A_b =  A & ((1u << 5) - 1);       //  ((1u << 5) - 1) --> 00000000 00011111
    
        // Split Image B into R, G, B  components
        unsigned short B_r = B >> 11;
        unsigned short B_g = (B >> 5) & ((1u << 6) - 1);
        unsigned short B_b = B & ((1u << 5) - 1);
    
        // Alpha blend components 
        /*Do I need to use 255(8 bit) instead of 32(5 bit), Why we are dividing by it , I have taken the ref from internet , but need little bit more clarification ??*/
        unsigned short uiC_r = (A_r * Alpha + B_r * (32 - Alpha)) / 32;
        unsigned short uiC_g = (A_g * Alpha + B_g * (32 - Alpha)) / 32;
        unsigned short uiC_b = (A_b * Alpha + B_b * (32 - Alpha)) / 32;
    
        // Pack result
        res= (unsigned short) ((uiC_r << 11) | (uiC_g << 5) | uiC_b);
    
     return res; 
    }
```

=====================
EDIT:
Adding method 2 ,is this approach is correct ?
Method 2:

```
                            //   rrrrrggggggbbbbb
#define RB_MASK      63519  // 0b1111100000011111        --> hex :F81F
#define G_MASK        2016  // 0b0000011111100000        --> hex :07E0
#define RB_MUL_MASK 2032608 // 0b111110000001111100000   --> hex :1F03E0
#define G_MUL_MASK   64512  // 0b000001111110000000000   --> hex :FC00


unsigned short blend_rgb565(unsigned short A,unsigned short B,unsigned char Alpha) {

  // Alpha converted from [0..255] to [0..31]  
  Alpha = Alpha >> 3 
  uint8_t beta = 32 - Alpha; 

  // so (0..32)*Alpha + (0..32)*beta always in 0..32

  return (unsigned short)
   (
        (   
            (  ( Alpha * (uint32_t)( A & RB_MASK ) + beta * (uint32_t)( B & RB_MASK ))  &  RB_MUL_MASK ) 
            |
            (  ( Alpha * ( A & G_MASK  ) + beta * ( B & G_MASK ))  &  G_MUL_MASK  )  
        ) 
        >> 5 // removing the alpha component 5 bit
    );
}
```

Comment: " is alpha bending is happening correctly ?" You do not know? Do you have test cases or at least pairs of sample input and expected output?

Comment: "can you please suggest better way?" In which way would you like to improve the shown code?  What aspect needs to be improved?

Comment: "I am getting some result , not sure that the right/best o/p, have some doubt based on alpha parameter." Please elaborate. What result do you get? Is anything noteworthy about it? "not sure that the right/best o/p" I cannot parse. Please rephrase. "have some doubt based on alpha parameter" what doubt is that? Please explain.

Comment: "Do I need to use 255 instead of 32, Why we are deviding by it , I have taken the ref from internet , but need little bit more clarification ?" If you would focus your question on that it could be answered. Please clarify whether you just want that explanation or whether anything indicates that the code is misbehaving.

Comment: `((1u << 6) - 1)`  looks like a mast. In my opinion, If you want a mask, you may make a `constexpr unsigned short mask_5bits` type marking with a meaningful name instead of making a comment. But this is personal opinion.

Comment: Do I need to use 255(8 bit) instead of 32(5 bit), I want to know the correctness of , Why we are dividing by it , I have taken the ref from internet , but need little bit more  help for 
 understanding it .

Comment: If you want to map 0-255 to 0-32 instead of 0-31 for alpha (which you should, otherwise you will always be darkening the image even at max alpha) then cast Alpha to a short or an int (or pass it in as one) and do `Alpha = (Alpha + (Alpha >> 5)) >> 3`

Comment: Sorry, you won't be darkening it, but you will be blending it 1:31 instead of 0:1

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to reduce the multiplies from 6 to 2 if you space out the RGB values into 2 32-bit integers before multiplying:

```
unsigned short blend_rgb565(unsigned short A, unsigned short B, unsigned char Alpha) 
{ 
    unsigned short res = 0; 
    // Alpha converted from [0..255] to [0..31] (8 bit to 5 bit)        
    Alpha = Alpha >> 3;
    // Alpha = (Alpha + (Alpha >> 5)) >> 3; // map from 0-255 to 0-32 (if Alpha is unsigned short or larger)
    
    // Space out A and B from RRRRRGGGGGGBBBBB to 00000RRRRR00000GGGGGG00000BBBBB
    
    // 31 = 11111 binary
    // 63 = 111111 binary
    unsigned int A32 = (unsigned int)A;
    unsigned int A_spaced = A32 & 31; // B
    A_spaced |= (A32 & (63 << 5)) << 5; // G
    A_spaced |= (A32 & (31 << 11)) << 11; // R
    
    unsigned int B32 = (unsigned int)B;
    unsigned int B_spaced = B32 & 31; // B
    B_spaced |= (B32 & (63 << 5)) << 5; // G
    B_spaced |= (B32 & (31 << 11)) << 11; // R
    
    // multiply and add the alpha to give a result RRRRRrrrrrGGGGGGgggggBBBBBbbbbb,
    // where RGB are the most significant bits we want to keep
    unsigned int C_spaced = (A_spaced * Alpha) + (B_spaced * (32 - Alpha));
    
    // remap back to RRRRRGGGGGBBBBB
    res = (unsigned short)(((C_spaced >> 5) & 31) + ((C_spaced >> 10) & (63 << 5)) + ((C_spaced >> 16) & (31 << 11)));
    
    return res; 
}
```

You need to profile this to see if it is faster, it assumes that multiplications you save are slower than the extra bit-manipulations you replace them with.

Comment: thanks for your input , but I have one doubt , I am trying to optimism the memory usage also. converting short into int , it will lead to  more memory consumption .

Comment: @ANSHUGANGWAR: on the opposite, the data will require less registers. But in any case, a handful of bytes, which are only used temporarily, make no significant difference.

Comment: Hi @samgak, 
1) what will the output of A_spaced / B_spaced 
2) In res   + means |(OR) ?
                                                                              
 (C_spaced >> 5) & 31) --> //Expecteed output :BBBBB  

                                                                                                         (C_spaced >> 10) & (63 << 5)) -->   //Expecteed output :GGGGGG00000 , instead of >> 10 , it should be 15

                                                (C_spaced >> 16) & (31 << 11) -->//Expecteed output : RRRRR00000000000  , instead of >> 16 , it should be 21

Comment: RRRRRrrrrrGGGGGGgggggBBBBBbbbbb :--> 31  bit ? ggggg is five time not 6 right, and it is due to the Alpha blending product ?

Comment: @A.G. correct, even though it has 6 bits, it's multiplied by a 5-bit value (same as in your code) so results in an 11 bit value GGGGGGggggg. I used + when computing res but it will give the same result as | because none of the bits overlap so there will be no carries. You can test that the function behaves the same as yours by calling both of them in a loop over all possible values of A, B and Alpha and checking they both return the same value every time.

Answer (score 1):

> can you please suggest better way wrt less temp variable

There is no advantage to remove temporary variables from the implementation. When you compile with optimizations turned on (e.g. `-O2` or `/O2`) those temp variables will get optimized away.

Two adjustments I would make to your code:

1. Use `uint16_t` instead of unsigned short. For most platforms, it won't matter since `sizeof(uint16_t)==sizeof(unsigned short)`, but it helps to be definitive.
2. No point in converting alpha from an 8-bit value to a 5-bit value. You'll get better accuracy with blending if you let alpha have the full range
3. Some of your bit-shifting looks weird. It might work. But I use a simpler approach.

Here's an adjustment to your implementation:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAKE_RGB565(r, g, b) ((r << 11) | (g << 5) | (b))

uint16_t blend_rgb565(uint16_t a, uint16_t b, uint8_t Alpha)
{
    const uint8_t invAlpha = 255 - Alpha;

    uint16_t A_r = a >> 11;
    uint16_t A_g = (a >> 5) & 0x3f;
    uint16_t A_b = a & 0x1f;

    uint16_t B_r = b >> 11;
    uint16_t B_g = (b >> 5) & 0x3f;
    uint16_t B_b = b & 0x1f;

    uint32_t C_r = (A_r * invAlpha + B_r * Alpha) / 255;
    uint32_t C_g = (A_g * invAlpha + B_g * Alpha) / 255;
    uint32_t C_b = (A_b * invAlpha + B_b * Alpha) / 255;

    return MAKE_RGB565(C_r, C_g, C_b);
}
```

But the bigger issue is that this function works on exactly one one pair of pixel colors. If you are invoking this function across an entire image or pair of images, the overhead of using the function call is going to be a major performance issue - even with compiler optimizations and inlining.  So if you are calling this function `row x col` times, you should probably manually inline the code into your loop that is enumerating over every pixel on an image (or pair of images).

Comment: thanks for your input , but I have one doubt ,Can we use uint8_t instead of uint16_t , and uint16_t instead of uint32_t , In your suggested code .I don't think it will make any operation overflow .And In end return the 16 bit output.

Comment: It won't save you any CPU cycles to reduce the variable size. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/P9d9vzdrM) vs [here](https://godbolt.org/z/PTanEhcn7).

Comment: What you didn't see is that I already wrote a unit test to validate that all combinations of variable values for a,b,and Alpha don't generate any overflow issues. Hence, no need to clamp the values.  Also, if you study the code, you'll see that it can't overflow as I have it above.

Answer (score 1):

In the same vein as @samgak's answer, you can implement more efficiently on a 64 bits architecture by "post-masking", as follows:

```
rrrrrggggggbbbbb
```

Replicate to a long long (by shifting or mapping the long long to four shorts)

```
---------------- rrrrrggggggbbbbb rrrrrggggggbbbbb rrrrrggggggbbbbb
```

Mask out the useless bits

```
---------------- rrrrr----------- -----gggggg----- -----------bbbbb
```

Multiply by α

```
-----------rrrrr rrrrr----------- ggggggggggg----- ------bbbbbbbbbb
```

Mask out the low order bits

```
-----------rrrrr ---------------- gggggg---------- ------bbbbb-----
```

Pack

```
rrrrrgggggbbbbb
```

---

Another saving is possible by rewriting

```
(1 - α) X + α Y
```

as

```
X + α (Y - X)
```

(or `X - α (X - Y)` to avoid negatives). This spares a multiply (at the expense of a comparison).

---

**Update:**

The "saving" above cannot work because the negatives should be handled component-wise.

Comment: can you help me understand samgak code ? is my understanding is wrong or the ret value is not proper.

Comment: In res + means |(OR) ? (C_spaced >> 5) & 31) --> //Expecteed output :BBBBB.......................... (C_spaced >> 10) & (63 << 5)) --> //Expecteed output :GGGGGG00000 , instead of >> 10 , it should be 15 ...............................................(C_spaced >> 16) & (31 << 11) -->//Expecteed output : RRRRR00000000000 , instead of >> 16 , it should be 21 – 
----------------
RRRRRrrrrrGGGGGGgggggBBBBBbbbbb :--> 31 bit ? ggggg is five time not 6 right, and it is due to the Alpha blending product ?
---------------
Also what will the output of A_spaced / B_spaced ?

Comment: I guess that he assumed RGB555.

Comment: For that last optimization, would the comparison need to be done component-wise for R G and B to avoid negatives?

Comment: @samgak: oops, sorry, this does not work.